# unable to locate file in DDMS view

Tags: android, file-io

I am generating a notification for classes according to my timetable. In the notification i am  providing action button if the user clicks this button a file for that class opens where attendance is marked for the corresponding class. I have written the following code

```
   public class Record extends BroadcastReceiver
    {public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
          {
         String f = intent.getStringExtra("class");

     String fname= f+".txt";
     System.out.println("File Name :" + fname);
     try 
        {   File name = new File(f+".txt");      
            if(!name.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("Creating file" + fname);

                name.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fname,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String str1= "1";
                fos.write(str1.getBytes());
                fos.close();
                       if(!name.exists())
                {
                    System.out.println("FILE NOT CREATED");
                }
            }

            else
            {    String inputString;
                 BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            context.openFileInput(fname)));
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
                    while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                           stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
                    }

                   int number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
                   number=number+1;
                   String str1 = String.valueOf(number);
                   FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fname,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                   fos.write(str1.getBytes());
                   fos.close();                                        
            }

        }

     catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }  
      }
```

So what i did is check if the file exists . if not then create one else increment the contents by one.

when i run this and click on the action button, i get 
1) File Name
2) Creating File

but don't get FILE NOT CREATED. this means the file is being created. But i cannot find the file in DDMS view.

I dont know where i am going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put fname on the disk as I doubt that you are creating file in a non authorized area on the disk

Use

```
String fname= getFilesDir() +"/" + f+".txt";
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives the following in logcat 
java.io.IOException: open failed : ENOENT(No such File or Directory)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably already created. `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` automatically creates the file in your internal app directory if not already there. The complete path to your internal app files directory is `/data/data/com.example.yourpackage/files`.

Is your phone rooted? Because you shouldn't be able to see the root folders in DDMS without it being rooted. If so, another way you can check is use a `File Manager` program on your phone. I use `ES File Manager`.